# copy selected row cell entries to other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to provide the capability to select either a row or column in a row and copy certain cells off the row into a different sheet.

For example...I have a list of renters (rows) each with the amount they owe and the amount collected on one sheet and the other sheet is a receipt. I'd like to enter the rent collected and have the receipt sheet updated automatically with the other sheets rows/individuals name and amount collected.

Is there a VB function to identify the active row?

If I can get that working the next thing would be adding/incrementing the invoice number.

Comment: You can use `Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select` to select active row

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `UsedRange` and the `Rows()` property to get your active row.

While `UsedRange` is not necessarily required, it would only select the used cells in that row as opposed to selecting the entire row of the workbook, which is very likely unneeded.

You can use this function:

```
Function rngActiveRow() As Range

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveCell.Parent
    Set rngActiveRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveCell.Row)

End Function
```

If you wanted to test it, you can try calling this function in a test sub to see it work:

```
Sub test()

    rngActiveRow.Select

End Sub
```